# MS Access - Pick Color From Combobox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm creating a plant database and in the plant detail form, I'd like a dropdown so the user can select the color the plant is, ultimately this would go on a summary report so all of the colors of the plants selected would show and the user can get an idea of what the plant colors would look like planted.

I'm using the Color Index of 56 colors and I made a table with colors (1-56) and used conditional formatting, but conditional formatting only goes to 50, plus I'm not sure on how to get only the color to show on the dropdown.

Comment: I would think 50 colors would be enough choices, remove 6 of them from the list. Can't display colors in dropdown list of intrinsic combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is idea how to display unlimited number of colors in continuous form or report without using conditional formatting:

- Create a table, which contains color ID and a column with stored pictures of desired colors, one pixel is enough, each color in separate row. Column data type - `OLE Object`, insert `Bitmap Image` with color sample.
- Join this table with your main table by color ID column
- Display colors in picture control `Bound Object Frame`, Size Mode should be Stretch or Zoom, one pixel picture will be tiled across whole picture control

Built-in dropdown cannot show color samples, but you can replace dropdown by form with desired samples, it's not complicated.